# How to know export proxy working or Not

Tags: git, proxy, export, firewall

To download some opensource code behind the office firewalls I am exporting the Proxy 
like this

```
export http_proxy=http://username:passwdatXYZ.com:portnumber
export https_proxy=http://username:passwdatXYZ.com:portnumber
export HTTP_PROXY=://username:passwdatXYZ.com:portnumber
export HTTPS_PROXY=://username:passwdatXYZ.com:portnumber
```

How do I know wether my this export with the above password and login is correct or not or working or not!

My pasword has a special character - "`!`" e.g it is `-> abcd!efgh` , so do I have to supply the password as `abcd%21efgh` (where `21` is the unicode for special character "`!`")

Since it isn't working, what would you change to those settings?

Answer (score 2):

I usually do a:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:abcd%21efgh@proxy.xxx.company:portnumber
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:abcd%21efgh@proxy.xxx.company:portnumber
set NO_PROXY=.company
```

(always use `http://...` both for `HTTP_PROXY` *and* `HTTPS_PROXY`)
In other words, I make sure the proxy isn't called for internal url ending by `.company`.

Depending on the proxy used, you special character may or may not be supported, so if the setting above isn't working, try *first* to change your password with a plain one (without any special character).

Comment: @Raulp just a word you can replace by any extension your company is using for its proxy. So if my proxy url ends witn ".company", I need to exclude from proxy calls any url ending with ".company" (because ihat url would reference the internal LAN/WAN of the company, not the world-wide-web).