# codeplex - Could not resolve host: nopcommerce.codeplex.com

Tags: git, clone, codeplex

I am trying my hardest (and failing) to clone nopcommerce from codeplex, but for what ever reason I always get the following output from typing:

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/nopcommerce nopCommerceGit
```

which results with the following output:

```
Cloning into 'nopCommerceGit'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git01.codeplex.com/nopcommerce/': Could not res
olve host: git01.codeplex.com
```

I have set my global name to my codeplex username and set my email to my personal email. Am I missing somthing?

Oh and I'm not behind a firewall {edit: whoops, not behind a proxy}

Comment: Do you need to use a proxy to reach the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up and pretty much didn't try again.. Turns out that it was my firewall Comodo's automatic sandboxer just ruining all my fun..

Solution: Disable auto-sandbox for 15 minuits, push your stuff, 15 minuits later sandbox is back :D then you gotta disable again :(.. I would prema disable but hey, I never get viruses and I go all over the internet so comodo is doin it's thing.

Comment: Maybe there's a white list where you can add specific domains? BTW, in your question it says "I'm not behind a firewall" :p

Comment: I'm going to blame being a retard on that... What I ment was a proxy... I am pretty freakin stupid though :|

Comment: Oh and I've looked and can't find any whitelist that works with sandboxing... I can tell it not to sandbox is but git references all this other crap because it really wasn't designed to be used on non linux based systems :|

Comment: Glad you found the issue. +1 for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The git clone url mentioned there in the [SourceControl project page](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README.md) is:

```
https://git01.codeplex.com/nopcommerce
```

So you can try a:

```
git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/nopcommerce nopCommerceGit
```

It does work:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git>git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/nopcommerce
Cloning into 'nopcommerce'...
remote: Counting objects: 109999, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (29594/29594), done.
remote: Total 109999 (delta 80193), reused 107487 (delta 78199)
Receiving objects: 100% (109999/109999), 251.38 MiB | 2.69 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (80193/80193), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (5326/5326), done.
```

Comment: Oops, that's what I've been using, I copied another thing I was trying to get it to work. I am sorry for my negligence, updating now.

Comment: @MichaelCrook ok, but your error message still references the wrong url.

Comment: my bad once again, didnt update output.. it's the same exceptit says the new url (probably why i didnt notice (git01.codeplex.com)

Comment: @MichaelCrook then it must be a proxy issue, because I can clone it without problem. Are you able to browse (HTML browser) the domain nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README.md ?

Comment: Yes I am.
For what ever reason I can only pull/commit via VS :( git just refuses to work anymore due to this darn could not resolve host bs

Comment: @MichaelCrook do you have a proxy to set? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17444005/6309)

Comment: Found out that it was comodo sandbox :(