# Git: "Failed to connect" during push over HTTPS

Tags: git, android-studio, azure-devops

I'm working on Android Studio, I use Git VisualStudio.com. 
I sent my work normally until this morning:

> Push failed.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyProject/': Failed to connect to xyz.visualstudio.com:443

I am behind a proxy and  everything is ok on my Windows 8 and Android Studio settings...
Whereas... Yesterday, at the same place with the same settings, pushes and pulls worked correctly.

When I try to reach this URL (https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyProject/) with my browser, all it is ok.

Comment: Please try to make "titles" of your questions more meaningful. Try briefly describing your problem. This will surely attract more people to your question than plain "git fatal error" title that could be anything. I've edited your post with an example of a better title - but please, read it and feel free to correct the title once again if you don't its current shape.

Comment: my question is not about the proxy configuration. Everything worked with the same configuration at the same place yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, I took such impression from your description. if so, then it's good you changed the title. Btw. Yesterday is not today. Today it does not work anymore. Something has changed. If you don't know what could have changed - methodically check every option. It isn't that impossible for some 3rd party software to change your network or porxy settings. But of course, it doesn't have to be it. You are on the spot, we only see what you told us.. You must diagnose what's the problem. You might try Wireshark or TcpMon to see where the Git actually tries connecting to. It'll probably show something.

Comment: Sure ! Yesterday is not today... I do not know what could be changed. Thanks for the tip about Wireshark. Result : Android Studio tries 3 times to push and fails (but I don't know why...)

Comment: I found! This is the new proxy configuration of my workplace...

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to configure proxy settings?

Yes, you can make sure, before launching your Visual Studio, that `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables are properly set.
As in "[How to know export proxy working or Not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17444005/6309)".

you see those same variables mentioned in "[Set Environment Variables (Team Explorer Everywhere)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh272656.aspx)" for Visual Studio 2013.

---

The [OP Andrés Talavera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045161/andr%C3%A9s-talavera) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863749/git-failed-to-connect-during-push-over-https/24864057?noredirect=1#comment38627068_24864057) being a proxy-related issue:

> This is the new proxy configuration of my workplace...

Comment: Visual Studio reads your system proxy settings and does not respect `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY`.  This question is, I think, about either Git for Windows or Android Studio with a visualstudio.com remote.

Comment: I use Android Studio as IDE for an Android project. I configured my proxy and gradle proxy settings correctly.

Comment: @AndrésTalavera maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/18356572/6309 could help? (local git config for http proxy)

Comment: Nope, I do not think it's proxy settings... Yesterday, at the same place with the same parameters, pushes and pulls worked correctly.

Comment: @AndrésTalavera Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.