# Unable to clone github public repo using HTTPS

Tags: git, github, bower, bower-install

I'm having a github public repo in my bower, when I'm doing bower install, I'm getting the following error:

> bower ECMDERR, exit code of #128 Permission denied (publickey)

I also tried to git clone this project directly, still got Permission denied. I'm using HTTPS request to clone.

Note: Its a public repo and its getting clone others PC. And I'm under cooperate proxy.

Exact error:

ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128 Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Additional error details:
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Did you set your HTTP(S)_PROXY environment variable? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17444005/6309)

Comment: Yes, I did set HTTP(S) proxy env variable.

Comment: Can you `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `GIT_TRACE=1` *before* `bower install` and see if the output has some clues in it?

Comment: "publickey"? Are you using an ssh url for the GitHub repo url?

Comment: Yes, that what confuse me too... I'm using HTTPS url, like https :// github.com/project-ulr

Comment: Any luck with `set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and `GIT_TRACE=1`?

Comment: nope. Even for angular mock I'm getting the same error. (https ://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git)